# React Custom Hook Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Very new to React and been trying to figure out custom hooks and keep getting stumped. Here's my latest, hoping someone can help me make sense of what I'm seeing.

I'm taking a very iterative approach to building up to a functional custom hook. Right now I have the following:

The custom hook:

```
const useHandleDeleteClick = () => {
    
    console.log('custom hook');
    return;

};

export default useHandleDeleteClick;
```

Component Code:

```
import { useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import useHandleDeleteClick from "./useCustomHookFile";

const ItemDetails = () => {
    const { customerId, id } = useParams();
    const handleDeleteClick = useHandleDeleteClick();
    console.log(handleDeleteClick);
        
    return (        
        <a href='#' onClick={() => handleDeleteClick()}>
            Do stuff
        </a>
    );
    
}
 
export default ItemDetails;
```

Two questions:

1. I see that the onClick of the "Do stuff" link is invoked when the page loads/is rendered. Is there a way to prevent that?
2. handleDeleteClick is undefined and I'm really not sure why so the onClick effectively does nothing.

If I can get this wired up correctly I can start to build in the actual desired functionality.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. It's not.
2. Your custom hook returns nothing - `return;`. That's why `handleDeleteClick` is `undefined`. Try `return () => console.log('click');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go over your code and address the issues you mentioned:

onClick Invoked on Page Load: This is not happening because of your onClick implementation. In fact, your onClick is correctly set up to invoke the handleDeleteClick function only when the link is clicked. If you're seeing something happen on load, it might be related to another part of your code or application.

handleDeleteClick is undefined: This is because your custom hook useHandleDeleteClick is returning undefined. When you use the return statement without a value in JavaScript, it returns undefined.

To fix this, you need to make sure your custom hook returns a function. Here's how you can modify your custom hook:

```
const useHandleDeleteClick = () => {
    const handleDelete = () => {
        console.log('Deleted!');
        // Add your delete logic here
    }
    
    console.log('custom hook');
    return handleDelete;
};
```

Now, your handleDeleteClick will be a function that logs "Deleted!" to the console when invoked.

Your component code should work as expected now:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useHandleDeleteClick from "./useCustomHookFile";

const ItemDetails = () => {
    const { customerId, id } = useParams();
    const handleDeleteClick = useHandleDeleteClick();
    console.log(handleDeleteClick);
        
    return (        
        <a href='#' onClick={handleDeleteClick}>
            Do stuff
        </a>
    );
    
}
 
export default ItemDetails;
```

Comment: Interesting what you say about the onClick not being actioned on load, it's really weird. The console logs I have in useHandleDeleteClick are absolutely firing. What I have basically mirrors what you laid out.

Comment: Interesting, if I add a function to the component code, have the onClick call the function, and then have that function call the "handleDeleteClick", then I don't see the "handleDelete" fire